# CakePHP read() is not returning a model name

Tags: cakephp

I am having trouble with my cakePHP and wondering if anyone else has experienced this.  I am trying to setup a User object.  I create the Model:

```
class User extends AppModel
{
}
```

I create the controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
  function view($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    $this->set('users', $this->User->read());
 }
}
```

and I go to the view page.  However, I am not getting what the cake documentation says I should be getting.  I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [FirstName] => 1
            [LastName] => 1
        )
)
```

when what I am expecting to see is

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [FirstName] => 1
            [LastName] => 1
        )
)
```

Also when I do a `$this->User->find('all');` I get back an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ([0] => Array (/*stuff here*/))
    [1] => Array ([0] => Array (/*stuff here*/))
    [2] => Array ([0] => Array (/*stuff here*/))
)
```

I have tried changing the name to Myuser (including the database table, controller, model, etc) and still have the same results, so I don't think it's related to a reserved keyword.
Has anyone run into this or, more importantly, does anyone have a clue how I might fix it?  Thanks.

EDIT:
I am using cake version 2.0.6.  I am using a MySQL 5.0.92 database.  I just have tried setting the name variable and it did not change my results.

Comment: Did you try setting $name in the Model and Controller?? `public $name = 'User';` in the Model, `public $name = 'Users';` in the Controller.

Comment: what cake version? especeially with 2.0 the `$name` tip is contraproductive. at least it should be.

Comment: I had a similar experience when I used SQL Server database. Is your case?

Comment: ahhhhhh >_< i had the same problem once, all i can remember is that it had to do with the mysql version, or maybe it was because of the php version.. check the [requirements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#requirements)

Comment: Last night I borrowed some webspace from a friend and copied my entire app over to their website (different host), and it worked just fine with the exact same code, so I'm starting to lean toward a problem with the PHP config or SQL version on the site I'm hosting it at :(

Comment: Your controller structure must be wrong for sure.Please follow this link. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/959/Controller-Attributes

Answer (score 2):

After an ENTIRE DAY of troubleshooting, I finally was able to solve it.

The cause is definitely an outdated pdo_mysql.so library. This is located in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/(latest directory)/pdo_mysql.so

The table name being returned in getColumnMeta was only added in a certain version due to this function request:
https://bugs.php.net/41416/

Now, the problem is, in some web hosts, PHP needs to be compiled with Easy Apache. Mine had to go through that as well just in order to enable PDO (it was initially disabled). But the problem is, for some reason, Easy Apache is downloading some obsolete source code everytime it runs. Running yum or installing any RPMs don't help either.

So here is what I did:
- I downloaded the latest PHP sources from the PHP site, extracted the tarball
- I ran Easy Apache, did a recompilation, and very quickly went to the console to watch it redownload the outdated PHP sources
- When the PHP sources have reappeared, I very quickly replaced the entire ext/pdo_mysql directory with the latest sources
- Easy Apache will compile httpd first, so you have some time to do the above step
- After the build is done, reboot.
- To check if your version of pdo_mysql.so supports the table name, execute this command:
strings -f pdo_mysql.so | grep ': table'
- There should be an entry there. The old version doesn't.
- By the way, I noticed that there are more copied of the pdo_mysql.so in /usr/lib/php/modules and /usr/lib/php/extensions, but it seems that the one in /usr/local is the one that is active. Nevertheless, I update all copies manually

NOTE: if you just try to update the pdo_mysql.so file, it will not work. You will get a segmentation fault, and the pages will render nothing. You need to recompile PHP using the above steps.

I hope this will help other people who will come across this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your table is named users and include the association explicitly

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $useTable = 'users';
    ...
```

You need to set the $uses variable to associate the User model with the controller if you are using any additional models.  Adding it explicitly even if there's just one will not hurt either...

for example

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    //Controller Name
    public $name = 'Users';

    //DB Config for desired connection
    public $useDbConfig = 'test';

    // Array of associated models
    public $uses = array('Store','User');

    //Array of Helpers used by Controller Views
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    ...
```

Also, check to be sure there are no edits in AppModel or AppController which may be accidentally contributing to the interactions here...  You may also consider dumping the value of the $uses to see what's there.

Comment: Tried setting the uses variable.  Didn't change anything.  Did a debug of it and saw
    Array
    (
        [0] => User
    )
I am thinking of just re-installing cake at this point :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out that the reason for it has to do with a function called PDOStatement::getColumnMeta.  This gets called on the queries that cakePHP runs is used by the framework to get the column name, column type, and table name.  However, for whatever reason, on the webhost I currently have, this function does not return the table name so cakePHP defaults to creating the array with a 0 index rather than a table name index.

```
$column = $results->getColumnMeta($index);
if (!empty($column['table']) && strpos($column['name'], $this->virtualFieldSeparator) ===  false) {
    $this->map[$index++] = array($column['table'], $column['name'], $type);
} else {
    $this->map[$index++] = array(0, $column['name'], $type);
}
```

still not sure how to fix it yet, but this is definitely why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. beastmaster

The reason why is that u using old version of PDO driver which has been been deprecated. the PDOStatement::getColumnMeta does not show [table]=name in old version

So solution here download new version of PHP which has build-in PDO. **DO NOT INSTALL PDO VIA PECL** coz u getting old version of PDO extension. and using

```
<?php phpinfo ?>
```

to check if it is installed properly. so u can use native PDO driver coming with PHP rather than use extension PDO driver.

By the way, Thank you for point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the problem. The cause was not  an outdated pdo_mysql.so library.

If you use cakephp 2.3.x and make sure to use PHP 5.2.8 or greater, you should check whether the **pdo_mysql** extension is enabled or disabled.

You can echo **phpinfo()** to check it. 
Note: the **pdo_mysql** extension is only enabled if you see *"PDO Driver for MySQL enabled"*, otherwise it is disabled.